# CSS isn't aligning my text

Tags: html, css

Basically I want the headers to float aligned to the text

but for some reason it's not working??

http://gyazo.com/670047956db62243c980124917102de7

My css

```
h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 35px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share html as well?

Comment: are you using h1 tag in your page? i can see h4 tag only..

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger/node inspector of your browser. It will show you how styles are applied to the elements and you can see in this case that the padding applies to all sides.

Comment: try sharing your html code

Comment: The text on the URL you provided is in a graphic ... http://i.gyazo.com/670047956db62243c980124917102de7.png ... The HTML and CSS for both the headers and the text, plus any html wrappers need to be looked at to determine what needs to be changed. IE the margin and padding for the text on the left must be the same for the as the headers on the left; when they are the same they are aligned. Share the needed info so the problem can be found.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try to remove the `padding: 35px;` and see how it looks (since it applies to all directions). To skip the left direction simply do `padding: 35px 0px` or `padding: 35px 35px 35px 0px`.
Secondly, the indent might come from a different style. To investigate further simply use the Inspect element option that comes built in on every modern browser. (You can access it by right clicking the element, or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I).